# Asymptotic Behaviour of a formula

Tags: asymptotics, approximation, bit-strings

I have the following hideous equation
$$ \frac{1}{n} \log_q (q^lx) $$
with
\begin{equation}
x=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{l} \rfloor -1} \left( \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n-(i+1)l}{l} \rfloor} (1-q)^j q^{n-(i+1)l-(l+1)j} \binom{n-(1+i+j)l}{j} - \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n-(i+1)l-l}{l} \rfloor} (1-q)^j q^{n-(i+1)l-l-(l+1)j} \binom{n-(2+i+j)l}{j} \right)
\end{equation}
with $1 \le l \le n$ and $ 2 \le q $.

I am interested in a analytical equation for the asymptotical behaviour with $n \rightarrow \infty$. $l$ and $q$ will have small values. Can anyone give me some hints, how to get a nice equation for $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Numerical simulations show that this equation approaches to the value $0.6958$ for the parameters $q=2,l=2$ and $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you encounter such a formula ?

Comment: I constructed it myself, I need this for some research. :-)

Comment: Let me rephrase : what does this formula compute ?